# " and ' being used in textarea for php script

Tags: php, html, forms, syntax

How can I allow " or ' in any of my form inputs and process it in php with out getting  syntax error I dont know where to begin to start trying to fix it.

i would assume you would negate it. How would i go about negating **"** and **'** in the inputs on the form.
I have tried this

`str_replace("\"","\\\"",str_replace("\'","'",$_POST['server_desc']))`

it works for the **"** but not for **'** how can i get it to work for both

Iam getting this error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Minecon, and won the award for \"Best PVP Server!\" LOLWeapons - Includes c' at line 23

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string() function.

Comment: Sidenote: snippets aren't for php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `mysqli_real_escape_string`

> mysqli::real_escape_string -- mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

Characters encoded are `NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.`

Comment: Should i process my form in the same php file the html part of the form is displayed or should it be in its own file in a scripts folder

Comment: you can process in the same file using if(isset($_POST)){ //process form }else{ //show your form}

Comment: Which is better? Same file or different file

Comment: That is based on your concept of coding, if you are in a framework structure, say model, view, controller, i recommend you have to write the html's in view, processing the inputs from form in controller and interactions with db in model. But if you are not in mvc concept i opt write in the same file as you dont have to keep another file.

Comment: currently i have a form on a php page and its action goes to another file and if it errors it comes back if not and its all accepted it goes to another file(not the one with the form)